# Hesitation markers like "uh, ehm" versus repetition

Tags: spoken-language

When listening to my 5-year-old son telling me a little story about dinosaurs, he used a lot of repetition in the following way:

> "The triceratops… the triceratops used his horns… the triceratops used his horns to fend off... the triceratops used his horns to fend off the T-rex."

I noticed that younger children seem to use a lot of "build-up repetition" as in the example above when hesitating in their speech, whereas older children (and adults) resort to filling syllables like "uh..", "er..." and so on.

Is there any explanation for this difference in speech hesitation?